# Creating Firestore Listeners in a mobx store (flutter)

Tags: flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore, mobx, bloc

I am currently working on a flutter app using firestore and mobx. I use mobx to keep the UI up to date, and make api calls to firestore (so the data flow is firestore -> mobx store -> UI). I want to set up listeners to listen for real-time changes in a firestore collection. Ideally, I would like to set up this listener in mobx, but I'm not sure how this would work - is a mobx store the right place to listen for firestore changes? One thing I'm worried about is that there is no dispose method in the mobx store in which I can detach listeners. I am wondering if this is an acceptable way to update variables in my store (and thus the UI, indirectly), or if I need to switch to BLoC/stream model. Any general advice about this issue (i.e. the best way to listen for real-time firestore updates and propagate the changes to the UI) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not using flutter but I guess it shouldn't be very different.

Here is an example of how I listen to a user profile changes in my app.

```
class UserModel {
  @observable id = ''

  updateDetails (userUpdate) {
    // update observable properties
  }

  destroy () {
    // Call destroy to remove listener
    if (this.stopWatch) {
      this.stopWatch()
    }
  }

  init () {
    // firestore onSnapshot returns a disposer, keep it on the instance
    this.stopWatch = fdb.collection('users').doc(this.id).onSnapshot((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        this.updateMyDetails(doc.data())
      }
    })
  }

  constructor ({id}) {
    // ...
    this.id = id
  }
}

const user = new UserModel({id: 'firestoreId')})
user.init()

// then any observer, like your UI, is listening to changes of the userModel data

//...

user.destroy() // for example when the user signs out.
```

Note that you could listen to changes outside of the model if you want to keep these concerns separated, instead of having this init function.

If you are wondering why I check `if (doc.exists)` it's because Firestore won't send you any error if the document does not exist. (like an http 404). You need to handle it yourself.

Comment: How would I access the user store throughout a react application. How would i inject, etc.